# Do non-local C++11 lambdas live in anonymous namespaces?

Tags: c++, lambda, namespaces, c++11, global-variables

A recent build of GCC 4.8 gives the following code, when in a header file:

```
auto L = [](){};

struct S
{
    decltype(L) m;
};
```

the following warning:

```
test.hpp:3:8: warning: 'S' has a field 'S::m' whose type uses the anonymous namespace [enabled by default]
 struct S
        ^
```

Why does the compiler consider the type of the lambda to use the anonymous namespace? I made the lambda global, I didn't use an anonymous namespace anywhere.

**UPDATE**: The compiles gives the same warning even if I put the lambda in an explicit namespace, like so:

```
namespace N
{
    auto L = [](){};
}

struct S
{
    decltype(N::L) m;
};
```

**UPDATE 2**: In fact, it seems even class scope lambdas have the same problem:

```
class N
{
    static constexpr auto L = [](){};
};

struct S
{
    decltype(N::L) m;
};
```

Comment: Funny, both of those with an empty `main` compile fine on 4.7.1.

Comment: @chris: It compiles fine with 4.8 as well. It's just a new warning added in 4.8.

Comment: Oh, I didn't even notice it was a warning.

Comment: Does the warning also appear at function scope?

Comment: http://liveworkspace.org/code/293f7b02e6dcaba05394b928d50c5266 no warnings

Comment: @IlyaLavrenov, That looks like GCC 4.7.1.

Comment: @Xeo: No, which is not surprising, since there's nothing to warn about when using a type in an anonymous namespace locally. (The purpose of the warning is to point out when a type in an anonymous namespace is 'exported' by being used as a member or base of a type that is not in an anonymous namespace. I guess that can lead to ODR violations.) What's surprising is that the lambda's type is in an anonymous namespace to begin with, seeing as I haven't declared any anonymous namespaces anywhere.

Comment: i guess the warning has to do with recent efforts to add ABI "type versioning" to GCC and binutils, supporting the transition of std::string in libstdc++ to a c++11 conforming implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCC's warning may have been a bit confusing, but its intention is certainly right. The type of the lambda is unnamed, and it is unique *in the whole program*. On the other side if your class isn't put in an unnamed namespace (which it, given your description, I suppose is not), your class is the same type in every translation unit that you include it into. Since the same class should have the same members, and not different members in different translation units, this is a violation (and leads to undefined behavior).

What's at least as bad is that `L` is `extern`, so that you will get "multiple definitions of L" linker errors once you include the header into multiple translation units.

Comment: I don't see how "unique in the whole program" implies "a different type in every translation unit". Could you clarify?

Comment: I'm very late to the party, but I think the idea is that the compiler basically "invents" a different type each time a lambda function is declared, even though different functions may have the same argument and return types. It's as if the type of `auto L = [](){}` is not just `void(*)()`, but also has a unique identifier tacked on, like `void(*)()#1`, and if `auto M = [](){}` appears in another file, the type of `M` might be `void(*)()#2`, and `auto N = [](){}` somewhere else would have type `void(*)()#3`, and so on. (This, or whatever is correct, might be useful to clarify in the answer)

Answer (score 7):

§5.1.2/3:

> The type of the lambda-expression (which is also the type of the closure object) is a unique, unnamed nonunion
>   class type — called the closure type — whose properties are described below. This class type is not
>   an aggregate (8.5.1). The closure type is declared in the smallest block scope, class scope, or namespace
>   scope that contains the corresponding lambda-expression.

So, unless you're defining the lambda expression in code inside an anonymous namespace, the lambda's type should not be contained in an anonymous namespace either.

Answer (score 4):

Unless I missed something, none of these should be in an anonyous namespace, though atleast both GCC and MSVC seem to put them there.

`§5.1.2 [expr.prim.lambda] p3`

> [...] The closure type is declared in the smallest block scope, class scope, or namespace
>   scope that contains the corresponding *lambda-expression*. [...]

Atleast Clang seems to get it right, the closure type resides where it should be.

(You can test in which namespace a lambda type resides by simply containing the lambda in some kind of warning / error producing code. The compiler should spit out its type along with the warning / error.)

Comment: How are you getting the compiler to output the name of the lambda in an anonymous namespace? With `auto L = [](){};
template <typename> struct incomplete;
incomplete<decltype(L)> M;`, I get `error: aggregate 'incomplete<<lambda()> > M' has incomplete type and cannot be defined` - no anonymous namespace!

Comment: @HighCommander4 `struct{}_ = []{};` spits it out on Clang and GCC atleast ([example](http://ideone.com/H67Xh)).

Comment: For me that shows `error: conversion from '<lambda()>' to non-scalar type '<anonymous struct>' requested` - again, the lambda is not in an anonymous namespace!

Comment: @HighCommander4: Interesting. Maybe it's just the warning that's buggy.

Comment: What is the error message for you (and with what build of GCC)?

Comment: Just did a quick test... MSVC 2010 had the same issue with putting lambdas in anoymous namespaces, but it was fixed in later versions.  See [here](http://ideone.com/s2UTd4).  It seems that it was a common issue in early implementations of lambdas.  I suspect it was an attempt to guarantee each lambda's uniqueness.  [Interestingly, it appears that in MSVC2010, multiple global lambdas in the same file are placed in the same anonymous scope, but non-lambda global entities are left in the global scope.  If you declare a global lambda, then use it to initialise a global variable, you'll see it.]

Answer (score 0):

I've not read the spec in this case, just thinking..., but, can you make a test?

Your lambda is too trivial and may turn to become a stateless lambda. A stateless lambda like yours can turn to be a simple C function by the compiler. There may be some rule to put this functions in the anonymous namespace so that they exist across a single compilation unit only.

So I suggest you to make it non-stateless, like refering to a variable, and see if it still lives in this anonymous namespace.

Comment: The backing function should not have an influence on where the lambda type itself is placed.